# Oop check if database table is empty

Tags: javascript, php, sql, oop

I have a selector wich gets information from the database. But when my database table is empty, the selector still shows up like this:

[image: what it looks like when my database is empty]

However, when my database is empty. I don't want to show the selector. but a message that says something like: Database is empty! Add something.

My code for the selector:

```
$results = $database->Selector();
        echo "<form name='form' method='POST' id='selector'>";
        echo "<select name='train_name' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";
        // Loop trough the results and make an option of every train_name

        foreach($results as $res){
                    echo "<option value=" . $res['train_name'] . ">" . $res['train_name'] . "</option>";
            }  
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br />" . "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add to list'/>" . "</td>";
        echo "</form>";
```

The function:

```
function selector() {
        $sql = "SELECT train_name, train_id FROM train_information ORDER BY train_name";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);   
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

EDIT:

Got this now:

```
$results = $database->Selector();
        if(count($results) > 0) {
            //Form etc here//
}else echo "nope";
```

It is working now! :D

Comment: `if(count($results) <= 0) { echo 'empty'; }`?

Comment: Where do i have to place this?? I placed it in the loop. and it stil shows me the result. i place it after the foreach call but before the {} and nothing happend

Comment: @VinodKumar well then the if has actually to be changed to `if(count($results) > 0) { /* your form logic */ }`.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER, Oh yes sorry. My mistake.